# While preview file I need to remove 'Show More' option Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

[image]I am using  `$A.get('e.lightning:openFiles')` to preview my file but user can edit the file details using 'show more' option. Can anyone please help how to remove it.

This is the function I am calling on filename link to preview my file:

```
 previewfile: function (cmp, event, helper) {
         var contentId = event.currentTarget.id;
         $A.get('e.lightning:openFiles').fire({
        recordIds: [contentId]
    });
```

Comment: Are you checking OLP and FLS before you open and display Content to your users, then doing something to enforce them? It seems that's what is at the root of your issue. Your user could try to make changes in your component, but shouldn't be able to commit them depending on your methods for retrieving records and saving them.

Comment: I am not checking FLS and OLP. My requirement was simple  I am displaying my filename as a link then, If user want to preview they can click on filename link, I am calling the 'previewfile' method. I didn't get your solution what exactly I need to do?